# InteliJ IDE 2021.2: How to adjust the header vertical space usage?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Is it possible to adjust the header rendering in InteliJ. Currently almost a centimeter of vertical is completely wasted to emptiness (Which is significant when working on the 15 inch mac laptop).

[image]

Going 'Full Screen' isn't acceptable option right now since then then it adds transition delay when going to another window like the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try Distraction Free mode: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ide-viewing-modes.html

> In Distraction-free mode, the editor occupies the entire main window with the source code centered. All other elements of the UI are hidden (tool windows, toolbars, and editor tabs)